# Facebook Object Debugger: meta property 'event:fbid' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph

I collect events on this website, so I tried to add Facebook Event ID into the OG meta tags based on the [open graph documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/event/), just like this:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="event" />
<meta property="event:start_time" content="2013-10-25T20:00:00+02:00" /> 
<meta property="event:fbid" content="305759189566213" />
```

however, the debugger says *"Object at URL 'http://bornaptar.hu/esemeny/162/' of type 'event' is invalid because the given value '305759189566213' for property 'event:fbid' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'."*
the event ID (parsed from the facebook event URL) seems to be fine, it returns all the event data in [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=305759189566213) at least.

what might be the problem?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

based on the [answer](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/250697881744436) I got from Facebook Support, this feature is no longer available:

> There is no longer an fbid field available for the "event" Open Graph
>   object type. We'll update the documentation to reflect this.